# How to Hide TeamViewer Side Panel?

Tags: teamviewer

[image: TeamViewer side panel]

How to hide/disable TeamViewer side panel?

Answer (score 0):

Under the TeamViewer Options, Advanced, enable "Automatically minimize local TeamViewer Panel".

Other than that, there is no way that allows you to do so; it would otherwise be a security concern....[click here for the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTsjs.png)